# xjc segmentation fault with xsd file

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I'm trying to use [xjc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html) to generate Java classes from a [DDEX](https://ddex.net/) schema, http://service.ddex.net/xml/ern/381/release-notification.xsd, but when I run the xjc tool it says Segmentation Fault right away. How do I figure out what is wrong with the xsd file or with the way that I am calling the tool?

```
$ xjc -d src -p com.mypackage release-notification.xsd
parsing a schema...
Segmentation fault
```

I opened the xsd file with https://www.oxygenxml.com/ editor and it said it was valid. Also the site https://www.corefiling.com/opensource/schemaValidate/ was able to validate the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the XML Java Compiler (xjc) to work with DDEX schemas, however, the [Apache XMLBeans library](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/) is able to parse them and generate Java beans. Also, it has pretty good error messages:

```
    $ java -classpath xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar \
         org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCompiler \
         -dl -d ~/ddex/class -src ~/ddex/src ddex381.jar \
         ~/ddex/381-release-notification.xsd
```